# MySQL: On duplicate entry, update different database?

Tags: php, mysql

I use the following code for inserting details or updating only the cost if the entry already exists in the DB.

```
$update = mysql_query
("
    INSERT INTO details (id, name, team, cost) 
    VALUES ('$id', '$name', '$team', '$cost') 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cost = '$cost' 
") 
or die (mysql_error());
```

Using PHP and/or MySQL, how would I go about updating a separate DIFFERENT database with a log of ONLY when changes happened. The info I'd want to store is id, name, team, old cost, new cost. I have the database set up, but have no idea how to get my page to recognize a duplicate, then run code when a duplicate happens.

Basically it is a soccer site that the prices change on. I want to update a database when prices change.

Thanks for any suggestions you can give, or please let me know if this question isn't clear.

Comment: You'll have to run *two* queries, which is not a great detail anyway.

Comment: Run `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM details WHERE id='$id'` before running this, if `$count==1` also throw it into the other db, else don't. Forget that; If `$id` is set you know it already exists in the table, if `$id` is not set you know it isn't.

Comment: @AmazingDreams Great thanks.... I think I need to sleep on it before trying again. I was hoping there was a way to do it from this query rather than having to make a new database call, but that's probably unavoidable.